# Can Protobuf serialized data be sent from gRPC server to client?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c++

In my Grpc server application, I already have the Protobuf serialized data that it received from a different server. Is there a way to avoid deserialization in the gRPC server and avoid creating the Protobuf response object and directly send theProtobuf serialized data to the client so client can do the deserialization ?

my grpc server API currently does this to create Protobuf response.

```
class SampleServiceImpl final : public SampleService::Service 
{
    Status SampleAPI(ServerContext* context, const Request* request, Response* response) override 
    { .......
//already has Protobuf serialized data"serialized_response_msg_buff"
        proto::Response response;
        any.ParseFromArray(serialized_response_msg_buff, serialized_response_msg_len);
        any.UnpackTo(response);....
    }
}
```

In my case, the Response object is very heavy and will end up doing deserialization twice, one in the above code and once by gRPC service when it sends to the client.
Is there a way to avoid the above deserialization and directly pass Protobuf serialized data to the gRPC client?